# How to get this value from this enormous list inside a dict inside a list that is inside dict...?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i'm learning python and some webscraping techniques.
I made a request from a website and i want to get a value from this confuse dict:

```
newDict = {'actions': [{'account_action_seq': 3186, 'action_trace': {'account_ram_deltas': [], 'act': {'account': 'test', 'authorization': [{'actor': 'test', 'permission': 'xfer'}], 'data': {'from': 'm.federation', 'm
emo': 'test', 'quantity': '0.0442', 'to': 'test'}, 'hex_data': 'test', '
name': 'transfer'}, 'action_ordinal': 5, 'block_num': 117988314, 'block_time': 'test', 'closest_unnotified_ancestor_action_ordinal': 2, 'context_free': False, 'creator_action_ordinal': 2, 'elapsed': 2, 'p
roducer_block_id': 'test', 'receipt': {'abi_sequence': 4, 'act_digest': 'test', 'auth_sequence': [['m.f
ederation', 2]], 'code_sequence': 5, 'global_sequence': 4798388072, 'receiver': 'test', 'recv_sequence': 1514}, 'receiver': 'pvwbq.wam', 'trx_id': '3'}, 'block_num': 117988314, 'block_time': '2021-05-08T00:56:14.000', 'global_action_seq': 4798388072, 'irreversible': True}], 'head_block_num': 117989564, 'last_irreversible_block': 117989233}
```

I want to print the value in 'quantity' that is 0.0442 but i don't know how to get to it.

Update:

```
act = conteudo.json()
act_list = act['actions']
act_trace = act_list[0]['action_trace']
act_act = act_trace['act']
act_data = act_act['data']
print(act_data['quantity'])
```

I reached the value with this code, but i don't know if it's the best way. Could you guys please analise?

Comment: You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You should know how to access a dict element by name, and a list element by position.  Simply nest those references in order, "peeling the onion" until you get to your desired element.  Since you haven't shown *any* attempt, this is not an appropriate question.

Comment: Try pasting your variable in a json viewer like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and formatting it. This helps to see the structure.

Comment: BTW, one problem I had working on this was due to the fact that the value you have in your question for `newDict` is syntactically invalid because it was split-up into multiple lines incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve problems like this is to pretty-print the data in order to understand its layout. Once you've done that, it's usually fairly easy to determine how to access the value(s) you want.

I usually use `json.dumps()` or `pprint.pprint()` to do this. In this case I used the former:

```
import json

newDict = {'actions': [{'account_action_seq': 3186, 'action_trace': {'account_ram_deltas': [], 'act': {'account': 'test', 'authorization': [{'actor': 'test', 'permission': 'xfer'}], 'data': {'from': 'm.federation', 'memo': 'test', 'quantity': '0.0442', 'to': 'test'}, 'hex_data': 'test', 'name': 'transfer'}, 'action_ordinal': 5, 'block_num': 117988314, 'block_time': 'test', 'closest_unnotified_ancestor_action_ordinal': 2, 'context_free': False, 'creator_action_ordinal': 2, 'elapsed': 2, 'producer_block_id': 'test', 'receipt': {'abi_sequence': 4, 'act_digest': 'test', 'auth_sequence': [['m.federation', 2]], 'code_sequence': 5, 'global_sequence': 4798388072, 'receiver': 'test', 'recv_sequence': 1514}, 'receiver': 'pvwbq.wam', 'trx_id': '3'}, 'block_num': 117988314, 'block_time': '2021-05-08T00:56:14.000', 'global_action_seq': 4798388072, 'irreversible': True}], 'head_block_num': 117989564, 'last_irreversible_block': 117989233}
print(json.dumps(newDict, indent=4))
```

Results:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "account_action_seq": 3186,
            "action_trace": {
                "account_ram_deltas": [],
                "act": {
                    "account": "test",
                    "authorization": [
                        {
                            "actor": "test",
                            "permission": "xfer"
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": {
                        "from": "m.federation",
                        "memo": "test",
                        "quantity": "0.0442",  # <- BINGO!
                        "to": "test"
                    },
                    "hex_data": "test",
                    "name": "transfer"
                },
                "action_ordinal": 5,
                "block_num": 117988314,
                "block_time": "test",
                "closest_unnotified_ancestor_action_ordinal": 2,
                "context_free": false,
                "creator_action_ordinal": 2,
                "elapsed": 2,
                "producer_block_id": "test",
                "receipt": {
                    "abi_sequence": 4,
                    "act_digest": "test",
                    "auth_sequence": [
                        [
                            "m.federation",
                            2
                        ]
                    ],
                    "code_sequence": 5,
                    "global_sequence": 4798388072,
                    "receiver": "test",
                    "recv_sequence": 1514
                },
                "receiver": "pvwbq.wam",
                "trx_id": "3"
            },
            "block_num": 117988314,
            "block_time": "2021-05-08T00:56:14.000",
            "global_action_seq": 4798388072,
            "irreversible": true
        }
    ],
    "head_block_num": 117989564,
    "last_irreversible_block": 117989233
}
```

With that information, I was able to come up with this:

```
quantity = newDict["actions"][0]["action_trace"]["act"]["data"]["quantity"]
print(quantity)  # -> 0.0442
```

Note that `quantity` is a string, *not* a numeric value.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I've reached an answer before but yours is much cleaner.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish the same thing — pretty-printing the data — such as that online jsonviewer someone mentioned, but I like this way and have made use of it many times.